# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando passar o PIN pelo código, para que o usuário não precise digitá-lo sempre, ele esta me retornando este erro:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng'

Esta é a função que estou utilizando:

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider LerDispositivo(RSACryptoServiceProvider key, string PIN)
{
    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName);
    SecureString ss = new SecureString();
    foreach (char a in PIN)
    {
        ss.AppendChar(a);
    }
    csp.ProviderName = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
    csp.ProviderType = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
    csp.KeyNumber = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2;
    csp.KeyContainerName = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
    csp.KeyPassword = ss;
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
    return rsa;
}
```

E acrescentei essas 3 linhas na minha função de assinar:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    Key = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509Cert.PrivateKey;
                    signedXml.SigningKey = x509Cert.PrivateKey;
                    signedXml.SigningKey = LerDispositivo(Key, "senhaaqui");
```

O erro ocorre nesta linha:

```
 Key = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509Cert.PrivateKey;
```

**EDIT**
Já verifiquei vários exemplos na internet, porém nenhum resolveu o meu problema.
Consegui achar este [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc336754-4b17-418d-86f2-e67a80271843/using-x509certificate2-to-get-privatekey-causes-cryptographicexception-quotinvalid-provider-type?forum=csharpgeneral), que tem uma explicação, porém não consigo adaptar ao código.

Seguindo o LINK acima, eu tentei fazer desta forma:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKeyProvider = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509Cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
                        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
                        signedXml.SigningKey = LerDispositivo(publicKeyProvider, "senhaaqui");
```

e ele retorna o mesmo erro:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.

Existe alguma maneira de converter RSACryptoServiceProvider para RSACng ? 
Toda forma que eu tento retorna o mesmo erro.

**EDIT**

Conforme a resposta do Pedro, fiz as alterações, porém mesmo assim sem sucesso, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> error CS0433: O tipo "CngPropertyOptions" existe em "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" e "System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Já tentei várias "soluções" que poderiam resolver o problema, porém nenhuma resolveu o problema ainda.

Comment: Pelos vistos a propriedade `PrivateKey` do objeto `x509Cert` não é do tipo que está a tentar fazer o `Cast`. Confirme em `Debug` se o tipo é mesmo esse.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Eu vi alguns exemplos na internet desta forma, tem alguma outra maneira de passar o PIN via código ?

Comment: Não digo que o código esteja errado, mas o `Cast` está com certeza. Tem que ver que tipo devolve `x509Cert.PrivateKey`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins eu verifiquei no `Debug` ParentWindowHandle = '((System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)x509Cert.PrivateKey).Key.ParentWindowHandle' threw an exception of type 'Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException', realmente ele é RSACng, porém não sei como corrigir.

Comment: `CryptographicException:` O valor da chave não é uma chave RSA ou DSA ou a chave é ilegível.
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @JoãoMartins tem alguma solução pra me auxiliar ?? Não consegui resolver

Comment: @LeandroAngelo dei uma olhada no link, porém não me ajudou, preciso passar o PIN pelo código, porém toda forma que tento, me retorna este erro, não sei como converter.

Comment: Que tal assim: `Key = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider).PrivateKey`?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo o problema acontece, porque preciso passar o PIN do certificado direto no código, para que o usuário não precise digitar toda vez que for assinar o arquivo, porém parece que em versões mais antigas, esse meu código acima funciona, e nas mais recentes não funciona, toda forma que eu tento ele me retorna este mesmo erro.

Comment: Hmmmm. Eu não testei e nem tenho como testar agora. Mas eu acho que do jeito que te passei não voltara o erro InvalidCastException. Ou voltará nulo ou a chave. Ou uma exceção qualquer por tentar acessar a variavel de um objeto não instanciado.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo eu já tentei desta forma, eu preciso colocar o certificado antes de `PrivateKey`, o erro que ele me retornou foi: `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.`

Comment: Ultima tentativa. Key = `(System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)(x509Cert.PrivateKey)`

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo mesma coisa, eu procurei exemplos de `RSACng` porém sem sucesso, não estou conseguindo resolver este problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Windows há duas gerações de APIs de criptografia:

- A geração antiga ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/cryptography-portal)), que inclui *Cryptographic Service Providers* (CSP), que é a tecnologia usada pela classe [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider);
- E a nova geração ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-portal)), *Cryptography API: Next Generation* (CNG), que é a tecnologia usada pela classe [`RSACng`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacng).

A propriedade [`X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey) retorna um objeto do tipo `AsymmetricAlgorithm`, que pode ser do tipo `RSA` ou `DSA`. A partir do .NET Framework 4.6 é possível usar o método de extensão [`X509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey), que retorna direto um objeto [`RSA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa).

Uma chave de certificado pode implementar as duas gerações criptográficas, ou apenas uma delas. No caso do seu certificado, parece que somente a nova geração criptográfica é implementada, por isso a propriedade `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` está retornando um objeto do tipo `RSACng`, que não pode ser diretamente convertido para o tipo `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, já que eles são totalmente diferentes.

Só que a rotina que você tem para informar o PIN do seu certificado de hardware só funciona com o tipo `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, então você terá que adapta-la para o tipo `RSACng`. Eu não tenho um certificado de hardware aqui para testar, mas escrevi uma rotina para você testar.

Primeiro a função `LerDispositivo()` (mantive o nome que você usou, mas agora você passa diretamente o certificado `X509Certificate2` para ela) testa para ver qual é o tipo de `RSA` recebido do certificado, se é **CNG** (*Cryptography API: Next Generation*) ou **CSP** (*Cryptographic Service Provider*), e então redireciona para a função que sabe como tratar de cada caso:

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

public static RSA LerDispositivo(X509Certificate2 cert, string pin)
{
   // Obtém a chave privada RSA do certificado.
   RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

   // Se a chave for do tipo CNG chama a função que trata desse tipo.
   RSACng rsaCng = rsa as RSACng;
   if (rsaCng != null)
   {
      return LerDispositivoCng(rsaCng, pin);
   }

   // Se a chave for do tipo CSP chama a função que trata desse tipo.
   RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = rsa as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
   if (rsaCsp != null)
   {
      return LerDispositivoCsp(rsaCsp, pin);
   }

   // A chave não era nem CNG nem CSP.
   return null;
}

private static RSA LerDispositivoCng(RSACng rsaCng, string pin)
{
   byte[] propValue;

   // O valor da propriedade deve ser informado como um array de bytes em
   // formato Unicode, e deve contar um caractere nulo como terminador.
   if (pin[pin.Length - 1] == '\0')
   {
      propValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin);
   }
   else
   {
      propValue = new byte[Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(pin) + 2];
      Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin, 0, pin.Length, propValue, 0);
   }

   const string NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY = "SmartCardPin";

   CngProperty prop = new CngProperty(NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY,
                                      propValue,
                                      CngPropertyOptions.None);
   rsaCng.Key.SetProperty(prop);

   return rsaCng;
}

private static RSA LerDispositivoCsp(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp, string pin)
{
   var securePin = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in pin)
   {
      securePin.AppendChar(c);
   }

   var cspParams = new CspParameters(
                           rsaCsp.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
                           rsaCsp.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
                           rsaCsp.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
                           null,
                           securePin);
   cspParams.KeyNumber = (int) KeyNumber.Signature;
   cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt |
                     CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

   return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
}
```

---

Referências:

> - [EncryptedXml DecryptDocument method error after .Net framework update - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434088/8133067)
> - [Verify Private Key Protection before signing with RSACryptoServiceProvider - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250758/8133067)
> - [CngKey Assign permission to machine key - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028524/8133067)
> - [CngKey.SetProperty - Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/CngKey.cs,6ab249a65c43e2ef,references)
> - [NCryptSetProperty function | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptsetproperty)
> - [Key Storage Property Identifiers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/key-storage-property-identifiers)
> - [How can I set PIN for a X509Certificate2 programmatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42630670/8133067)

Comment: Nesta linha `new CspParameters(` ele me retorna `Erro CS1729 "CspParameters" não contém um construtor que aceita 5 argumentos`

Comment: Estranho, qual versão do .NET Framework você está usando? De qualquer forma, deixe o construtor do `CspParameters` só com os 3 prmeiros parâmetros então, e coloque o `securePin` direto na propriedade `cspParams.KeyPassword` como você estava fazendo antes. Mas, se a sua chave era do tipo CNG, ele nem deveria ter entrado nessa rotina... Em nenhum momento ele passou pela rotina `LerDispositivoCng()`?

Comment: Eu até comentei ela, porque eu verifiquei no `debug` que ele não entrava nela, mas ele retorna erro nesta linha: `rsaCng.Key.SetProperty(prop);` Retornando o erro: `WindowsCryptographicException: Não há suporte para a operação solicitada` a versão do .NET Framework é 4.7

Comment: O seu certificado é do tipo A3? Qual tipo de dispositivo?

Comment: Tipo A3,utilizo cartão.

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint nessa linha que está dando erro dentro da função `LerDispositivoCng()` e execute na Immediate Window o comando: `? rsaCng.Key.HasProperty(NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY, CngPropertyOptions.None)`. Se retornar um erro tente executar o mesmo comando de novo, mas com a opção `CngPropertyOptions.Persist`, e me diga quais foram os resultados.

Comment: Quando eu executo o comando ? ele retorna `error CS0433: O tipo "CngPropertyOptions" existe em "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms,` e com o `Persist` ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: E esse certificado sempre pede um PIN quando você vai usa-lo?

Comment: Sim, em toda emissão de nota, ele pede o PIN, por este motivo, gostaria que ele já puxasse do banco.

Comment: Altere a criação do objeto `CngProperty` para o seguinte comando: `new CngProperty(NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin), CngPropertyOptions.Persist);` e veja o que acontece. Você fez as alterações na função `LerDispositivoCsp()`? Ela funcionou?

Comment: Acontece o mesmo erro, tentei adicionar pelo nuget a referência `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` pensei que poderia ser isso, porém instalei e o mesmo erro ocorre. Não, ele não chega nem a entrar no `LerDispositivoCsp()`

Comment: Mariana, tente mudar a linha `NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY = "SmartCardPin"` para `NCRYPT_SECURE_PIN_PROPERTY = "SmartCardSecurePin"` e use essa nova constante `NCRYPT_SECURE_PIN_PROPERTY` na criação do objeto `CngProperty`: `new CngProperty(NCRYPT_SECURE_PIN_PROPERTY, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin), CngPropertyOptions.Persist)`. Tente também com a opção `CngPropertyOptions.None`.

Comment: Fiz conforme me auxiliou porém novamente sem sucesso, ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86653/discussion-between-pedro-gaspar-and-marianac-costa).