# Erro ao assinar xml passando o PIN automaticamente

Tags: c#, xml

Eu tenho este código que seleciona o certificado de acordo com o serial passado:

```cs
public static X509Certificate2Collection SelecionarCertificado(string serial)
{
   X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
   var Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
   X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serial, true);

  return fcollection;
}
```

E essa parte aqui na assinatura, para passar a senha automaticamente:

```cs
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
//signedXml.SigningKey = x509Cert.PrivateKey;
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(x509Cert));
RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
Key = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509Cert.PrivateKey;
signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
signedXml.SigningKey = Certificados.LerDispositivo(Key, PIN);
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url;
```

Porém o que acontece, quando tenho dois certificados na minha máquina, ele retorna senha inválida. Alterei as senhas para ficarem iguais, porém neste caso ele não retorna erro de PIN inválido, porém ele assina com o certificado errado, que retorna um outro erro.
É como se a consulta que eu faço não ficasse valendo de nada.

Esta é a função `LerDispositivo()`

```cs
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider LerDispositivo(RSACryptoServiceProvider key, string PIN)
{
    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName);
    SecureString ss = new SecureString();

    foreach (char a in PIN)
    {
        ss.AppendChar(a);
    }

    csp.ProviderName = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
    csp.ProviderType = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
    csp.KeyNumber = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2;
    csp.KeyContainerName = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
    csp.KeyPassword = ss;
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);

    return rsa;
}
```

Já tentei linha por linha, alterei algumas coisas, e mesmo assim acontece. Se tiver apenas um certificado conectado, funciona perfeitamente, tudo indica que ele pega o primeiro certificado por ordem alfabética, pois quando estou assinando o outro não retorna o problema.

**EDIT**

Analisando o código, eu cheguei na conclusão que os dois certificados conectados tem o mesmo nome/`ProviderName`:

```
csp.ProviderName = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
csp.ProviderType = key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType;
```

Por isso que está confundindo, tem alguma forma de diferenciar, para ele saiba o certificado correto ?

Comment: Mariana, você já tentou passar para a função `LerDispositivo` o objeto que representa o certificado do tipo `X509Certificate2`, como eu sugeri naquela resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347796/86952, ao invés de passar um objeto do tipo `RSACryptoServiceProvider` (que é como você está fazendo)?

Comment: @PedroGaspar eu tive que voltar a fazer dessa forma, pois tive inúmeros problemas, e ocorre isso. Eu não sei se fica em cache, como funciona, o que realmente acontece, pois quando eu entro na função `LerDispositivo()` eu não consigo ver que certificado vem selecionado na hora. Porém quando ele seleciona o certificado, o `x509Cert` vem com o certificado correto, por isso não entendo o porque ele seleciona o outro. Se é algo que falta passar, algo do tipo.

Comment: @PedroGaspar editei a pergunta, explicando o que eu desconfio que seja.

Comment: Como você pega o certificado da coleção retornada pela função `SelecionarCertificado`? Você já se certificou de que o certificado retornado por essa função é o certificado correto?

Comment: @PedroGaspar sim, ele pega o certificado correto ai, o problema está aqui `key.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName` pois os dois certificados possuem nomes iguais, então ele sempre pega o primeiro. Com a ajuda deste link https://www.oipapio.com/question-1951681 consegui resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na função `LerDispositivo()` mude a linha:

```
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
```

para:

```
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
```

Veja o que diz a documentação do enum [`CspProviderFlags`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cspproviderflags) (usado na propriedade [`CspParameters.Flags`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.flags)):

> `UseDefaultKeyContainer` => Use key information from the **default** key container.
>   `UseExistingKey` => Use key information from the **current** key.

Também vale lembrar que o número serial do certificado não é totalmente único, talvez seja melhor usar o *thumbprint* para identificar unicamente cada certificado, usando a opção `X509FindType.FindByThumbprint` ao invés da opção `X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber`:

[What is the difference between serial number and thumbprint? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35694)

Embora creio que isso não afete no seu contexto atual, já que os dois certificados aparentemente são do mesmo fornecedor.